# I want to get the url of the webpage which is loading after clicking a button

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

here I am getting the url of the previous page.

```
LookUpDict.driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='ns__30899058_jsel_div1_contextMenu_alertsdijit_Menu_5_menuItem_1_CreateTicket_ProxyHFC']").Click(); 
String ticketUrl = LookUpDict.driver.Url;
LookUpDict.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(ticketUrl);
```

Comment: Can you please format code properly?

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void CurrentUrl() {
         String pURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(“<xpath>“)).click();  
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         String cURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
            if(pURL!= return){
                System.out.println(cURL);
                            }
                    else{
                System.out.println(“No new URl”);
                }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the URL **after** the click which is after the navigate happens. If you want to get the URL **before** the navigation/click you need to rearrange your code.

```
String ticketUrl = LookUpDict.driver.Url;
LookUpDict.driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='ns__30899058_jsel_div1_contextMenu_alertsdijit_Menu_5_menuItem_1_CreateTicket_ProxyHFC']").Click(); 
LookUpDict.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(ticketUrl);
```

You can also just use `Driver.Navigate().Back();` to avoid having to store the previous URL.